# Prove there is a bijection φ : R(X) → P(X)

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

For a set $X$, let $R(X)$ be the set of equivalence relations on $X$ and let $P(X)$ be the set of partitions of $X$. Prove there is a bijection $\varphi : R(X) \to P(X)$.

Stuck on how to proceed with this. I understand that equivalence relations and partitions are in essence the same. But in terms of writing a proof, I am really lost how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You say that they are in essence the same -- can you show in what way this holds? That is, if I give you an equivalence relation, can you come up with its corresponding partition and vice versa? This would define such a $\varphi$, it then remains to show that it is a bijection.

Comment: In addition to platty's advice, it might help to write down exactly what an element of $R(X)$ and an element of $P(X)$ might look like.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/understanding-equivalence-class-equivalence-relation-partition) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/converting-equivalence-relations-to-partitions).